# Redirect in to Gmail in ios

Tags: ios, gmail

i am new in iOS.i make an application that shows contact us page.in contact us page i make a one button with gmail when it pressed then i want to redirect on gmail. and also i make a one button it text contain website name then i want when it pressed the website will open in default browser how it is possible????
please give me any resources for it...

i write a code for gmail on button pressed event

```
-(IBAction)gmailbuttonpressed:(id)sender
   {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.gmail.com"]];
   }
```

but it not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enter a completre URL like `http://www.gmail.com`.

```
- (IBAction)gmailbuttonpressed:(id)sender {
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.gmail.com/"]];
}
```

---

Just a small remark for readability you should camcelCase you method names, thus your method should be name `gmailButtonPressed:`.

Comment: Yes for that you use [`MFMailComposeViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/index.html) or if you need to do it with a link: `mailto:some@email.fake`

Comment: any solution for Skype like as a mail???? i also want to send mail from Skype. Because in my action sheet 2 buttons one is Gmail and second is Skype

Comment: Yes, but seriously you can find all these with some googling : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745885(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)navigateToURL:(id)sender
{
    UIApplication *ourApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSString * urlString = @"http://www.gmail.com/";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    if([ourApplication canOpenURL:url])
    {
        [ourApplication openURL:url];
    }
}
```

This works fine for me...